# How can a non-zero matrix $A$ be found such that Adj$(A) = 0$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Is it possible to find a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that it's adjoint is $0$?

Comment: Adjoint with respect to what?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$